# DT Reload within RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Within shiny how would I go about updating values within a DT table without it repainting the entire table and thus flickering on each update.

The following example compares both the standard tableOutput with DT::dataTableOutput.
Note the flickering on each update of dataTableOutput.
Is there away to avoid this and have a smoother user interaction? ui.R and server.R example below.

```
require(shiny);require(DT)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sliders"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
        "integer", "Integer:",
        min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
      ),

      sliderInput(
        "decimal", "Decimal:",
        min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5, step = 0.1
      ),

      sliderInput(
        "range", "Range:",
        min = 1, max = 1000, value = c(200,500)
      ),

      sliderInput(
        "format", "Custom Format:",
        min = 0, max = 10000, value = 0, step = 2500,
        pre = "$", sep = ",", animate = TRUE
      ),

      sliderInput(
        "animation", "Looping Animation:", 1, 2000, 1,
        step = 10, animate =
          animationOptions(
            interval = 300, loop = TRUE,
            playButton = "PLAY", pauseButton = "PAUSE"
          )
      )
    ),

    mainPanel(tableOutput("values"),
              DT::dataTableOutput('DTtable'))
  )
))


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Name = c("Integer",
               "Decimal",
               "Range",
               "Custom Format",
               "Animation"),
      Value = as.character(
        c(
          input$integer,
          input$decimal,
          paste(input$range, collapse = ' '),
          input$format,
          input$animation
        )
      ),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  })

  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })
  output$DTtable = DT::renderDataTable(rownames = FALSE,
                                       {
                                         sliderValues()
                                       },
                                       options = list(processing = FALSE))
})
```

It looks like the ideal solution would be to implement the reload functionality:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: That is not possible (at least not straightforward) at the moment, but you can file a feature request to https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues (please include the link to this question)

Comment: Oh actually it has been filed by someone else; https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/168